# Replacing numbers based on length and first 3 charcters

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to replaced numbers on a range that contains mobile numbers of clients. I would like to change the numbers that are not 6 digit ,7 digit ,10 digit, and 11 digit numbers also I also would like to change 10 digit numbers whose first 3 digits are not "032" . Here is what I have come up so far:

```
Sub changetold()
    Dim rCel As Range
    Dim sTxt As String
    Dim first3numbers As String
    Dim lastrow, i, currentcell As Long

    Const MaxLength As Long = 11
    Const MinLength As Long = 6
    Const MidLength As Long = 7
    Const MaxmidLength As Long = 10

    first3numbers = "032"

    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "AC").End(xlUp).row
    End With

    currentcell = 12

    For i = 13 To lastrow
        currentcell = currentcell + 1
        sTxt = ActiveSheet.Range("CW" & currentcell).Value

        MsgBox (Len(sTxt))

        If Len(sTxt) <> MaxLength Or Len(sTxt) <> MinLength Or Len(sTxt) <> MidLength Or Len(sTxt) <> MaxmidLength Then
            sTxt = "101011"
        End If

        If Left(sTxt, 3) <> "032" And Len(sTxt) = MaxmidLength Then
            sTxt = "101011"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The code does change the cells but the problem is it is inaccurate. I would like to know how this will be done correctly like the sample image below:

[image: Initial data]

[image: Desired result]

Comment: Whats your question? Wheres your problem?

Comment: (1) "*I want to change numbers*" is not a good description of what you like to achieve. You need to be much more specific. [Edit] your question and add what your code actually does and what you expect it to do and if there are any errors (where and which errors). You might read [ask]. (2) Side note (not the solution): If you do this `Dim lastrow, i, currentcell As Long` only the last variable is `Long` the others are `Variant` you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, currentcell As Long`

Comment: If these are **numbers** (and not text), how will the first character be a `"0"`?  You may need to consider using the `.Text` property if you have numbers with a specific cell format.

Answer (score 3):

I think the code would be like this

```
Sub changetold()
    Dim sTxt As String
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AC").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For i = 13 To lastrow
        sTxt = Range("CW" & i)

        Select Case Len(sTxt)
        Case 6, 7, 11
        Case 10
            If Left(sTxt, 3) <> "032" Then Range("cw" & i) = "101011"
        Case Else
            Range("cw" & i) = "101011"
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout:  Thanks. I mistake.

Comment: ++ `cse 10` should be `Case 10`. You also have lot of unnecessary code which you can get rid of :). I have fixed your post. If you do not like then feel free to revert it

Comment: @SiddharthRout: thank you.Because, I also not test.  there is mistyping.

Comment: No Worries. Fixed it

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 2):

> sTxt = ActiveSheet.Range("CW" & currentcell).Value

Nothing is happening because you are storing the value in a variable, making changes to it but never writing it back to the cell.

Also instead of using so many `Ifs`, use `Select Case`. It will make your life easier :)

Is this what you are trying? (**untested**)

```
Sub changetold()
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AC").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 13 To lastrow
            Select Case Len(.Range("CW" & i).Value)
                Case 6, 7, 11
                Case 10: If Left(.Range("CW" & i).Value, 3) <> "032" Then .Range("CW" & i).Value = 101011
                Case Else: .Range("CW" & i).Value = 101011
            End Select
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```